# Background css animation not working at firefox

Tags: animation, css

i have some css animated button.

```
.bottom_panel ul li.bottom_panel_button_04 {
    background: url('../img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_131.png') center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: myfirst 2s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: myfirst 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: myfirst 2s linear infinite;
    animation: myfirst 2s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes myfirst {
    0% {background: url('../img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_131.png') center center no-repeat;
    }
    50% {background: url('../img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_131_on.png') center center no-repeat;
    }
    100% {background: url('../img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_131.png') center center no-repeat;
    }
}
```

On Chrome everything is fine but firefox can't fire this animation... what is wrong?

Comment: can you show an example in http://jsfiddle.net/ for better understanding like this because it's work for me check this http://jsfiddle.net/HG993/

Comment: Which version of Firefox do you use? @sandeep This example works in my browser.

Comment: i'v check it on priv version at windows and it still not working :(

Comment: ok, i'v create some fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SzXDh/

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@-moz-keyframes`to `@keyframes` and add `@-webkit-keyframes` for Saffari and Chrome (and all Chromium-based browsers)
You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v9umgfeu/).
And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4hqpd100/) is the link to your (working) example.